# How to select downline users using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, binary-tree, recursive-query

I want to select downline users against a user id.

This is my table structure:

```
"userid", "sponsorID", "username"
```

And the data into the table is:

```
1, 0, noman
2, 1, jani
3, 2, usman
4, 3, hassan
5, 4, ahmad
6, 5, haroon
7, 1, sabir
```

I want the data like this:

```
"Select * from table where sponsorID = 1
```

This should select all the users of downline, means it should selects user 2 first, then it will also select user 3 because user 2 is sponsored by user 1 and user 3 is sponsored by user 2 and will select whole downline with this scenario.

I have tried:

```
select * from table where sponsorID = '1'
```

But it selects only a one user, and I want the whole downline users data.

I don't know how to do the query in mysql to get desired data. If anyone knows please give me an example.

Comment: what is downline users?

Comment: @KUMAR downline means all the referal users of a user.

Comment: user 7 is directly sponsored by user 1 in what order should he appear? I mean user 2 and his tree will be above that?

Comment: @Peter Darmis see the answer thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can solve this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select userid, sponsorid, username, 1 lvl from mytable where sponsorid = 1
    union all
    select t.user, t.sponsorid, t.username, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.sponsorid = c.userid
)
select * from cte
```

The anchor of the recursive query selects all users sponsored by user `1`. Then, the recursive part follows the relationships, selecting all all users sponsed by the previously selected user, until the tree exhausts.

As a bonus, I added the `lvl` column, that represents the depth of each node in the tree.

Note that this assumes no circular references in the tree.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: thanks. I would have flagged this too (and in my opinion, that's an easy call for moderators...).

Comment: Welcome. Well, I got an answer back from a moderator  in my 2nd flag. Apparently it isn't against the rules to ask for personal information. Ok... I'll remember not to do that again LOL!! Oh well, the beauty of it I guess... is that I keep on *learning* Cheers! Oh, the mod said to use "no longer needed" would have sufficed.